# livewire dispatchBrowserEvent is not triggering alert

Tags: javascript, laravel-livewire

I have a livewire component which has an update() function to update the component when it changes. The update() function is called and updates the item in the database as required. At the end of this function i run a dispatchBrowserEvent() to confirm the update but the corresponding function in my js file is not being called and thus the alert is not being triggered.

I have been using this method from the docs https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/events#browser

The livewire component:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire;

use App\Models\Item;
use Livewire\Component;

class EditItem extends Component
{
    public int $item;
    public string $date = '';

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.edit-item');
    }

    public function update()
    {

        $item             = Item::find( 1 );
        $item->date       = now();

        $item->save();

        $this->dispatchBrowserEvent('update-item', ['item' => $item->id, 'date' => $item->date]);

    }
}
```

its blade file:

```
<div>
    <button wire:click="update">Update Me!</button>
</div>
```

in my app.js I have the following:

```
jQuery(document).ready( function($) {
    /** LIVEWIRE EVENT ACTIONS **/
    window.addEventListener('update-item', event => {
        alert( 'Date updated to: ' + event.detail.date + 'on item with id of ' + event.detail.item );
    })

});
```

Comment: you should change name function update to another name example edit , because has update function already in livewire.

Comment: Not sure thats right unfortunately... the event is triggered in php and the database is updated (I have also confirmed using xdebug and a breakpoint in the function). Just that the javascript isn't fired by the dispatchBrowserEvent. the event is also fired but it doesn't fire the event in the app.js file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turned out i hadn't ran `npm run dev` so the javascript didn't exist. after running this all was good.

Answer (score 2):

remove this code in app.js

```
jQuery(document).ready( function($) {
    /** LIVEWIRE EVENT ACTIONS **/
    window.addEventListener('update-item', event => {
        alert( 'Date updated to: ' + event.detail.date + 'on item with id of ' + event.detail.item );
    })

});
```

in blade

```
<div>
        <button wire:click="update">Update Me!</button>
 
    <script>
        document.addEventListener('update-item', event => {
           alert( 'Date updated to: ' + event.detail.date + 'on item with id of ' + event.detail.item );
        })
    </script>
</div>
```